# getting codeigniter to work on cherokee

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, cherokee

I just set up a cherokee server to test out and so far I am loving the performance and ease to set up. There is one issue though, codeigniter seems to not work too well.

I always get "Access Denied"

How do you set up codeigniter with cherokee server?

Thanks!

Comment: What configurations have you done so far ?

Comment: Directory /system List & Send ; Directory /Application List $ Send ; Extensions php FastCGI ; Default Redirection Internal ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

Comment: For completeness's sake: are you able to view other static (non-codeigniter) pages? In other words: are you sure the problem is CI?

Comment: Alright, so you guys pointed in me in directions I hadn't thought of (silly me). Permissions where wrong for the entire CI structure. After changing those I did the following in Cherokee [[[ Extension php Fast CGI FINAL; Directory /media (where I store css + images) List $ Send NON-FINAL; Default Redirection Internal ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 FINAL ]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To others who will read this.

Cherokee follows the behaviours in a specific way (Top to Bottom)

Here is what you must do in this order

create rule Directory /media and change the handler to List & Send (this is where you will want to place your css, images, js and such, and make this non-final

change default to Redirection, change the handler to type: internal, RegEx : ^(.*)$, Substitution : /index.php/$1

Create new rule with wizard->languages->php, ensure it's handler is FastCGI, balancer is Round Robin and the php interpreter is 127.0.0.1:47990, make this on final

---

Drag the extensions php to the first in the list, directory /media second and default last.